# Error alloc: invalid block: 04882D78: f8 3

Tags: python, tkinter

im new at python and im making a software with tkinter lib. The program works fine but when i close the program it appears the error presented in the title. Depending on what ive oppened from the software the block shown in the error changes.
Does anyone knows what this error means, and can I ignore it? It only appears when i close the program.
Thanks

Comment: can you give us a piece of code please ?

Comment: Im sorry, im with no wifi and i only have internet on the phone, whenever I can I will